# Restricting access in django at the model level

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model and I'd like to restrict access to objects based on the authentication level of the user. Anonymous users may only see a subset of the objects while authorized users have access to all objects. Reading through the django book I find that I could use checks like, is_authenticated() in my views and implement my logic based on that condition. But I don't want these checks shotgun splattered all over my code, instead I'd like to be able to give my models some intelligence: the models should only make available the objects that are visible to the current user's permissions.

Here are a couple of the models I'm working with:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    VISIBILITY_CHOICES = (
    ('P', 'Private'),
    ('SP', 'Semi-Private'),
    ('PUB', 'Public')
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    visibility = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=VISIBILITY_CHOICES)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to= get_upload_to)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
```

An example of a query I make would be: collection_ids = Image.objects.values_list('collection',flat=True).distinct() -- In this case I'd only want to check against those collection ids that the user is authorized to view (i.e public/private/semi-private).

Is it possible or do I have to put authorization logic in my views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in the query example you give (`Image.objects.values_list('collection',flat=True).distinct()`), `request` is never mentioned - so how would that query be able to check the current user?

But that doesn't mean you have to do it in the views - you can add methods to the model itself, or even subclass QuerySet to add a method to check against the current request, like `.filter(foo=bar).allowed_for_user(user)`.

See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576649/16361

Which links to an ancient blog post by yours truly, although I seem to have broken the link in that answer, sorry - the correct URL is:

EDIT: Remove a domain taken over by NSFW content and a dead link.

Also, just to make it clear - the code itself doesn't have to live in your views, but ultimately will need to involve the request object one way or another, so you will have to *call* it from your view.

Comment: I believe that is where the 'controller' part comes in from the term Model View Controller. This should either live in the view or in a separate set of logic that the view can call with its context. You really don't want to clutter your model with a bunch of view specific logic.

Comment: Not trying to be contrarian, but I don't see why. Sure, from a purity point of view, mixing stuff is bad. But I use Django for web applications, and I don't think it's inappropriate to have that reflected in my models. For example, it's not generally frowned upon to have methods that generate URLs for an object in the model definition. Why wouldn't we use the same logic for "can this request access me" methods?

Comment: Thanks for the links and I'll look into subclassing QuerySet.

Comment: I agree that you could do anything you want. And yes my answer does stem from a purity perspective. But I think its these types of guidelines that keep an application clean and understandable. If you need to figure out where your data is being filtered for a user context, you could always assume its in a view. The view is also the place that contains the request context. There are object-level permission apps that generate permissions for users to objects, but they also dont do any type of data filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Putting authentication onto the model is the wrong place for this logic. The views are exactly the correct place for this logic to live, which is why django provides the various auth decorators to protect views such as login_required()

The models job is to provide the layer of data access to the database. You would then create any number of views to visualize the data in the way you want. If you need anonymous views of data, create a view that checks if the user is authenticated, and formats the data appropriately.

Comment: What if I'd like to implement GraphQL??

Comment: @WolfgangLeon, what do you mean by this question, in terms of wanting to add authentication logic at the model level?

Comment: After doing some research I found out graphene ( GraphQL for Django ) resolvers returns info.context.request. We could filter by request.user when retrieving the queryset in the Query class.   http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/authorization/#limiting-field-access

Comment: Yes but that exact link you provided describes doing the authentication logic at the view/controller level and not the model. The model just has a foreign key to associate posts with users. The view checks actual user authentication and then formats an appropriate query to filter results for just that user. The model should always just be concerned with data and not middleware or presentation concepts.