# Can I add a custom method to a Django queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Suppose I have two models, in a one-to-many relationship:

```
from django.db import models

class Quantity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Measurement(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField()
    quantity = models.ForeignKeyField(Quantity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And I make some records...

```
weight = Quantity.objects.create(name="Body Weight in kg")
Measurement.objects.create(value=80, date="2020-01-01", quantity=weight)
Measurement.objects.create(value=81, date="2020-01-02", quantity=weight)
Measurement.objects.create(value=80.6, date="2020-01-03", quantity=weight)
Measurement.objects.create(value=80.1, date="2020-01-04", quantity=weight)
Measurement.objects.create(value=79.5, date="2020-01-05", quantity=weight)
Measurement.objects.create(value=81, date="2020-01-06", quantity=weight)
Measurement.objects.create(value=81, date="2020-01-07", quantity=weight)
```

Is there anyway I can calculate metrics from the queryset like this...

```
weight.measurement_set.all().average()
weight.measurement_set.filter(date__gt="2020-01-04").average()
weight.measurement_set.all().sum()
```

...where I define the relevant methods somewhere...

```
def average(queryset):
   return sum([m.value for m in queryset]) / queryset.count())

def average(queryset):
   return sum([m.value for m in queryset])
```

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576622/in-django-can-you-add-a-method-to-querysets) from 2011 but the answers seem a little out of date and don't seem to work. I am using django 2.2 currently.

Comment: Yes, althoug you can simply calculate the average with `.aggregate(r=Avg('value'))['r']` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can subclass the `QuerySet` class, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Sum
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class CustomQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def average(self):
        return self.aggregate(_total=Avg('value'))['_total']

    def sum(self):
        return self.aggregate(_total=Sum('value'))['_total']
```

Note that it is more efficient here to make [**`.aggregate(..)`** calls [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) here, since these will run an aggregate at the *database*, not at the Django/Python level.

Next we can make a custom manager with our `CustomQuerySet` as `_queryset_class`:

```
from django.db import models

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    _queryset_class = CustomQuerySet
```

and then we can add a manager to our model:

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField()
    quantity = models.ForeignKeyField(Quantity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = CustomManager()
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way to support both `queryset.objects.custom_method(xxx)` and `queryset.objects.filter(xxx).custom_method(xxx)`.

```
# refer to django's source code: django/db/models/manager.py

from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from django.db.models.manager import BaseManager

class SearchQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def search(self, keywords):
        return self.filter(name__contains=keywords)

class SearchManager(BaseManager.from_queryset(SearchQuerySet)):
    pass
```

then use as the normal manager.